# Get JSON data directly from rows loop without scanning in Golang

Tags: sql, sql-server, go

I have a function that processes a database query and return the rows. I'm using `rows.Next()` function to loop and scan each row. For that I'm using `rows.Scan()` function. Here is my code snippet.

```
tsql := "SELECT * from Users;"

// Execute query
rows, err := db.QueryContext(ctx, tsql)
if err != nil {
    return -1, err
}

defer rows.Close()

// Iterate through the result set.
for rows.Next() {
    var name, location string
    var id int

    //Get values from row.
    err := rows.Scan(&id, &name, &location)
    if err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }

    fmt.Printf("ID: %d, Name: %s, Location: %s\n", id, name, location)
}
```

Is there a way to get each row data in JSON format without scanning? Thank you

Comment: "s there a way to get each row data in JSON format without scanning?" No.

Comment: Do you want to avoid the scan or do you want some universal scanning option, which can scan any fieldset to a JSON without defining variables for it?

Comment: Yes, use [FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server) so you can retrieve your results as a single JSON value.

Comment: rows.Scan is just the name of the function to map the data into the variables you provide and has nothing to do with the json in itself. See https://go.dev/doc/database/querying for a bit more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Using the below query will give the output as JSON,

```
 SELECT * from Users FOR JSON AUTO;
```